# Filtrar dados no sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela `clientes` com as colunas:

> ```
> nome
> cidade
> email1
> email2
> ```

Não são todos os clientes que têm cadastrado e-mail. Como faço pra montar uma instrução `sql` onde só retorna clientes que contenham `email1` ou `email2`?

Comment: já tentou algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
SELECT
nome, cidade, email1, email2 
FROM
clientes
WHERE
(email1 is not null and email1 <> '') OR (email2 is not null and email2 <> '')
```